# Have mechanical butler's bell, would like to ring it with push button

Tags: communication, servo, solenoid, button

I have been recommended to post here! Basically I have a butler bell
which I'd like to ring from a few floors away with the use of a push button. I have arduinos, ethermegas, spark/particle core, but I wonder if I am over or under thinking things. How would YOU make this work? I have a few electrical parts and I'm not averse to buying a few more. Ideally I'd prefer simple and reliable over complicated and unreliable.

[image: butler bell]

Comment: Are all the ropes and cranks still installed?

Comment: How about an RC filtered dual oneshot , FET driver and rotary motor driver from hobby market that can rotate bell (tiny gear motor). One second on and one second to return to static position from gravity before retrigger enabled.

Comment: Or a cheap little solenoid with a battery and a push-button will work too https://www.aliexpress.com/popular/9v-solenoid-actuator.html

Comment: I would do a linear displacement sensor on the handle side, and a servo on the bell side.  That will let you transmit the (e)motion of the ring more faithfully.

Comment: If I had a butler's bell that I wanted to use, I would hire someone to do that

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the wiring and go for the wireless switch and solenoid puller from a bell transformer. various solenoids are noisy or linear motors with soft end stop snubbers are quieter like in HDD VCM voice coils. off 12V supply.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZUh2mp2Hc8

Or use a linear wireless servo controller that can reach with a front door lever connected to a pot with a spring.  The pot would have to enable a battery operated switch to transmit the servo position to conserve battery power.

"May I have some Tea daneee."

"yes my lord"